# playwright handle JS initiated request and retrieve the response for scraping

Tags: python, screen-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

The overall goal is to use Playwright for Python, to scrape a web page.

However, web page has some dynamically rendered info, like the Google Map. And I need to be able to get the longitude and latitude from it. I'm not sure how to retrieve it from the JS code, since JS is used to render it.

However, JS makes a request and the response payload contains the data I need.

How can I:

- load the page,
- scroll to the given DOM element, so the map get's rendered,
- wait for the specific request (to Googlel Maps API) to be finished,
- get the response, and
- combine it with the rest of data I have scraped from the static content of the page.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)

    context = browser.new_context(
        viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080}
    )
    
    page = context.new_page()

    
    # These are handled by respective functions
    # yet I'm not sure how to return response
    # here in this execution context
    page.on("request", intercept_request)
    page.on("response", intercept_response)
    
    page.goto('...')
    
    page.wait_for_load_state('domcontentloaded')
    
    # Scroll to the div with class "prices"
    prices_div = page.locator('div[class*="google-maps-url"]')
    prices_div.scroll_into_view_if_needed()
    
    
    content = page.content()
    
    # I want to be able to get the result from the response 
    # and scrape the page content here, combining all of it
    # before I save it in file.
    
    page.close()
    browser.close()
```

This is all synchronous code. Should I do it in async version?

One issue I have found out is that this script never ends. And this bugs me too.

Comment: I don't think async or sync will matter, but it's very hard to help without the site and a runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I would say that this doesn't need to be minimal reproducible code since it really is conceptual thing. I figured sync/async should not be the issue here, but I left the room for doubt.

Comment: Many people think that it's just conceptual, that you can eyeball an answer. That's true about 1/100th of the time in my experience, having answered hundreds of web scraping questions. It doesn't appear to be the case here, but if I'm wrong, someone else will answer.

Comment: Half a year later, still no answer, so it'd be good to have that complete example so someone can assist.